# Overriding mac's input forms

Tags: html, macos, input

How can I override the input forms that viewing a site on mac adds? It displays like other inputs just fine in windows. Thanks :)

http://i40.tinypic.com/653kts.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a javascript dropdown menu. Other than that, though, I'm not sure there's any way. It's a little like trying to format inputs of type 'file'. Here's how I'd probably do it:

```
<ul id="pulldown">
    <span>One</span>
    <li id="One" checked>One</li>
    <li id="Two">Two</li>
    <li id="Three">Three</li>
</ul>

ul {
    display: block;
    width: Xpx;
}

li {
    display: none;
}

$('ul').click( function() {
    $(this)
        .children('li')
        .show();
    $(this)
        .children('span')
        .hide();

    $(this).children('li').click( function() {
        $('li').hide();
        $('ul span')
            .text($(this).text())
            .show();
    });

});
```

Comment: I feared I'd have to do that D:

Comment: Hey, circumventing what should be simple controls is fun! :|

Answer (score 0):

Different platforms have different standard controls. It will also look different, say, in Firefox on Ubuntu. If you want all your controls to have a particular look rather than taking on the standard appearance, you'll have to [create that look](http://www.oscaralexander.com/tutorials/how-to-make-sexy-buttons-with-css.html) yourself.